# How can I get the citation for an R package without installing it?

Tags: r, citations

I know that `citation("packagename")` gives the citation of an installed package. How can I retrieve this citation without having to install the package (e.g., on the internet/github page)?

Answer (score 0):

If the package is in the CRAN repository you can get the citation information on the index page of the package under the Citation section. See for example cran.r-project.org/web/packages/randomForest/citation.html, you can just replace the randomForest name with any other package name.

Comment: I don't think this works for every package. I tried this for dplyr and the page doesn't exist: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dplyr/citation.html

Comment: @OliverOliver You are right, the index page for dplyr exists but there is no citation section, they didn't include it. I don't know why, I guess you have to use `citation()` in this case.